# Core 2 Razor AccesDeniedPath

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-authentication

I was following a Connect() video where they are securing a core 2 MVC app. In it, they added options for AccessDeniedPath and LoginPath

[image]

However, I'm using Razor, instead of MVC and let VS generate the log in code for mode, utilizing a database. My code looks as follows:

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, MyRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            options.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
            options.Filters.Add(new AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());
        })
            .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
            {
                options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/Account/Manage");
                options.Conventions.AuthorizePage("/Account/Logout");
            });
    }
```

AccessDeniedPath can't be added in AddMvc, AddRazorpagesOptions nor in AddIdentity.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

API for configuring application cookie options changed from ASP.NET Core 1.x to 2.x

```
 services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(opts =>
        {
            opts.LoginPath = "/Home/ErrorForbidden";
            opts.AccessDeniedPath = "/Home/ErrorLoggedIn";
        });
```

read
[Migrating Authentication and Identity to ASP.NET Core 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x) for more information.

Comment: So even with

            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, MyRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

I use ConfigureApplicationCookie to override or specify how it should handle the user session once the use is authenticated?

Comment: `AddIdentity` , `AddEntityFrameworkStores` and `AddDefaultTokenProviders` serves it's own purpose. `ConfigureApplicationCookie` is for cofiguring cookie options.